# MS Excel - How to refresh a cell automatically every 5 seconds?

Tags: vba, excel, refresh

I have a cell in my Excel sheet and I need this cell to be refreshed every 5 seconds.

MS Excel itself enables to set refreshing but it is only every 1 minute and that is insufficiently too long..

I need some code in VBA or macro set to be run every 5 seconds and do exactly what would be done if I clicked Refresh every 5 seconds as it is shown here:

[image: Refresh]

Somehow I didn't find any example of that I have absolutely no clue how to do that as I don't know how to work in VBA..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it, now it works:

```
Sub UpdateCell()
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:5"), "List1.UpdateCell"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Application.OnTime to schedule the auto refresh.  Do create the below VBA subroutine and execute.  It will auto calculate cell A1 every 5 seconds.

```
Sub UpdateCell()
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:5"), "UpdateCell"
End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't work. If I click Run (VBA) nothing happens, the code seems not to run at all..

Comment: Is your targeted refreshed cell in cell A1?

Comment: Yeah, now it seems to be refreshing (the cursor changes to loading mode every 5 seconds) but the value in the cell stays the same..

Comment: Can you provide more details on the cell formula or what do you want to accomplish through refreshing ?  If the refresh depends on click or some other event, we will need to enhance the code differently.

Comment: The cell is loading simple text from a .txt file. It works when I click the button as shown in the picture above.

Comment: I could record some macro where I actually click on the button and then I save and run the macro every 5 seconds via VBA.. But I don't know how to run macro in VBA..

Comment: I have updated the subroutine to refresh all instead .. The downside is that you are refreshing the whole workbook every 5s.  The other means is to refresh the specific data connection ONLY.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126433/discussion-between-albertlau14100-and-totallama).

Answer (score 2):

The other answer describe how to refresh the whole page but the guy asking the question said he only wanted to update one specific cell.

**This is how to update (calculate) cell A1 every 5 seconds.**

```
 Sub Calculate_Range()    
   Range("A1").Calculate    
   Application.OnTime DateAdd("s", 5, Now), "Calculate_Range"    
 End Sub
```